# Find Unique value from an array based on the array's string value (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

so I want to find unique values from an array.
so for example I have this array:

```
const mainArr = ['shape-10983', 'size-2364', 'size-7800', 'size-4602', 'shape-11073', 'size-15027', 'size-15030', 'size-15033', 'height-3399', 'height-5884']
```

so I want to find the first matching value for each unique item.
for example, in the array, I have two strings with the **shape** prefix, six items with the **size** prefix, and two items with the **height** prefix.
so I want to output to be something like

```
const requiredVal = ["shape-10983", "size-2364", "height-3399"]
```

I want only the first value from any set of different values.

Comment: Are "shape", "size", and "height" already in another list somewhere, like `prefix_list = [....]` or some such?

Comment: actually, they are the name and id's combination from a list. I have to compare them with the required values

Comment: If you already have the list, please show that in your post, because that greatly simplifies the solution.

Comment: sure I will add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest solution will be to iterate on the list and storing what you got in a dictionary

```
function removeSimilars(input) {
    let values = {};
    for (let value of input) {//iterate on the array
        let key = value.splitOnLast('-')[0];//get the prefix
        if (!(key in values))//if we haven't encounter the prefix yet
            values[key] = value;//store that the first encounter with the prefix is with 'value'
    }
    return Object.values(values);//return all the values of the map 'values'
}
```

a shorter version will be this:

```
function removeSimilars(input) {
    let values = {};
    for (let value of input)
        values[value.splitOnLast('-')[0]] ??= value;
    return Object.values(values);
}
```

Comment: really bro I already had the idea but didn't know the way or didn't have this much knowledge to actually use that.
thanx man anyways

Comment: and one thing is there any function in js called splitOnLast? seems like a type. thanx anyway, it will work with the split as well.

Comment: Can you please tell the use of ??= thing?

Comment: I modified the code a bit. but thanx. please check the code in my answer section

Answer (score 0):

If, as you mentioned in the comments, you have the list of prefixes already available, then all you have to do is iterate over those, to find each first element that starts with that prefix in your full list of possible values:

```js
const prefixes = ['shape', 'size', 'height'];
const list = ['shape-10983', 'size-2364', 'size-7800', 'size-4602', 'shape-11073', 'size-15027', 'size-15030', 'size-15033', 'height-3399', 'height-5884']

function reduceTheOptions(list = [], prefixes = [], uniques = []) {
  prefixes.forEach(prefix => 
    uniques.push(
      list.find(e => e.startsWith(prefix))
    )
  );
  return uniques;
}

console.log(reduceTheOptions(list, prefixes));
```

Comment: bro your solution is quite good but the thing is the array is dynamic and I really don't have the prefix required before the actual array

Comment: Then I'm somewhat confused as to why you said "they are the name and id's combination from a list", which tells us that there _is_ a list that you rely on (even if that's an implied list from a set of DOM elements that you can just querySelectorAll and then map over).

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and get the type and use it aks key for an object along with the original string as value. At result take only the values from the object.

```js
const
    data = ['shape-10983', 'size-2364', 'size-7800', 'size-4602', 'shape-11073', 'size-15027', 'size-15030', 'size-15033', 'height-3399', 'height-5884'],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, s) => {
        const [type] = s.split('-', 1);
        r[type] ??= s;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer man!! but can you please tell me the use of ??= thing?

Comment: @AliMir, it is a [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), which checks if the left side is `null` or `undefined` and assigns the right value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function getRandomSet(arr, ...prefix)
{
  // the final values are load into the array result variable
  result = [];

  const randomItem = (array) => array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  prefix.forEach((pre) => {
    result.push(randomItem(arr.filter((par) => String(par).startsWith(pre))));
  });
  return result;
}


const mainArr = ['shape-10983', 'size-2364', 'size-7800', 'size-4602', 'shape-11073', 'size-15027', 'size-15030', 'size-15033', 'height-3399', 'height-5884'];

console.log("Random values: ", getRandomSet(mainArr, "shape", "size", "height"));
```

Comment: bro your solution is quite good but the thing is the array is dynamic and I really don't have the prefix required before the actual array

Answer (score 0):

I modified the @ofek 's answer a bit. cuz for some reason the ??= is not working in react project.

```
function removeSimilars(input) {
let values = {};
for (let value of input)
    if (!values[value.split("-")[0]]) {
        values[value.split("-")[0]] = value;
    }
return Object.values(values);
```

}

Answer (score -1):

create a new array and loop over the first array and check the existing of element before in each iteration if not push it to the new array

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanx for the effort bro but it is not clear can you please explain a little more